# Mapping Windows-1252 encoding to UTF8 in C

Tags: macos, utf-8, windows-1252

How do you programmatically convert a C-string with encoding Windows-1252 (a.k.a. CP1252) to UTF8?

Comment: It's a perfectly clear and valid question, oh close voter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows? First call `MultiByteToWideChar` and then `WideCharToMultiByte`.

On a Mac or Linux: call `iconv_open` and then `iconv` as needed.

In general: incorporate the ICU4C library.

Comment: On a Mac. Checking out the ICU4C library now - thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a code page conversion, which is language/paltform specific.

If you want to implement it: [Windows-1252 on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (there is a link to the [conversion table](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WindowsBestFit/bestfit1252.txt))

Some solutions:

- Windows: [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- python: [decode()](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html)
- Linux: [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) (just one of the many)

etc...